# Java object monitors

Tags: java, multithreading, object

Looking for some assistance with a college assignment , really stuck with this one, would appreciate some help ... is it synchronization ?

Consider the code shown below:

```
 public class Q3 { 

 public static void main(String args[]) { 
     new Q3(Integer.parseInt(args[0])); 
 } 

 public Q3(int keyholdersRequired) { 
 SecretChest secretChest = new SecretChest(keyholdersRequired); 
 for(int i = 0; i < keyholdersRequired; i++) { 
 new KeyHolder(secretChest).start(); 
 try { 
 Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random() * 5000)); 
 } catch (InterruptedException ie) {} 
 } 
 } 
} 

class KeyHolder extends Thread { 

 private SecretChest secretChest; 

 public KeyHolder(SecretChest secretChest) { 
 this.secretChest = secretChest; 
 System.out.println("New Keyholder Arrived..."); 
 } 

 public void run() { 
 if(secretChest.unlock() == true) 
 System.out.println("Secret chest unlocked"); 
 } 
} 

class SecretChest { 

 private int keysStillRequired; 

 public SecretChest(int keysRequired) { 
 keysStillRequired = keysRequired; 
 } 

 public boolean unlock() { 
 keysStillRequired--; 
 return true; 
 } 

}
```

In this program, new `KeyHolder` threads are started intermittently. Each 
KeyHolder then calls the unlock method on the `SecretChest` to which it 
has been given a reference. The unlock method should return when the 
`SecretChest` in opened. The `SecretChest` should not be opened until the 
required number of `KeyHolder` threads have called the unlock method. The 
number of KeyHolders required is passed to the program as a command line 
argument.

As it stands, the output from the program, for 3 KeyHolders is:

```
java Q3 3 
New Keyholder Arrived...   
Secret chest unlocked   
New Keyholder Arrived...   
Secret chest unlocked   
New Keyholder Arrived...   
Secret chest unlocked
```

The desired output is:

```
java Q3 3 
New Keyholder Arrived...   
New Keyholder Arrived...   
New Keyholder Arrived...   
Secret chest unlocked   
Secret chest unlocked   
Secret chest unlocked
```

Using Java’s object monitors, make the necessary changes to the SecretChest 
class above to produce the desired behaviour.

I got this working using

```
class SecretChest { 

 private int keysStillRequired; 

 public SecretChest(int keysRequired) { 
 keysStillRequired = keysRequired; 
 } 

 public boolean unlock() { 
     keysStillRequired--;

 if(keysStillRequired == 0) { 
 return true;
 }

 return false;

 }
```

But I dont think this is whats being asked for, the question asks to use Javas Object Monitors ... is there another way to do this ? I tied using syncronise and notify but I am not sure how to use them.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are not doing anything with keysStillRequired

It should be decremented and ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code :

```
public class Q3 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Q3(Integer.parseInt("3"));
    }

    public Q3(int keyholdersRequired) {
        SecretChest secretChest = new SecretChest(keyholdersRequired);
        for (int i = 0; i < keyholdersRequired; i++) {
            new KeyHolder(secretChest).start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 5000));
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
        }
    }
}

class KeyHolder extends Thread {

    private SecretChest secretChest;

    public KeyHolder(SecretChest secretChest) {
        this.secretChest = secretChest;
        System.out.println("New Keyholder Arrived...");
    }

    public void run() {
        secretChest.unlock();
        System.out.println("Secret chest unlocked");
    }
}

class SecretChest {

    private int keysStillRequired;

    public SecretChest(int keysRequired) {
        keysStillRequired = keysRequired;
    }

    public boolean lock() {
        return keysStillRequired > 0;
    }

    public synchronized void unlock() {
        keysStillRequired--;
        // for last thread this condition gives false
        if (lock()) {
            try {
                // all threads except last are waiting here
                super.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // the last thread wakes up all previous threads
        super.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's already bad that Volodia did your HW. Now you want him to explain it to you? How about if you do your part and at least try to debug through it?

Comment: Apologies, I did get this workin myself ( I should have included the code) with the code below , but I dont think thats what the quesion is asking ... I need to used object monitors, and thats where I am struggling.        keysStillRequired--;
   synchronized(this){
 if(keysStillRequired == 0) { 
 return true;
 }
 
 return false;

Comment: Listen, I don't know how to stop thread except using while loop to check if keysStillRequired > 0. Anyway I edited code to put decrement into synchronized block

Comment: Please, post your final or correct solutions. Thank you!

Comment: I have done this by using wait and notifyAll to stop and resume threads.